# 404 error and other errors when deploying github pages

Tags: reactjs, github, web-deployment, github-pages

I am trying to deploy my portfolio website built with react. I am using github pages to deploy the page.

This is the website I used when I got a 404 error in deploying. https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/23058

This is the website I am trying to deploy: https://shivam242001.github.io/

On opening the site I initially see the [404 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awPxT.png) in the console and when I click refresh I see this in the [console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flZcc.png)

This is the git repo: https://github.com/Shivam242001/Shivam242001.github.io

I really need some help, I have been stuck on this for way too long. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Because you set the wrong `home page`

`"homepage": "https://github.com/Shivam242001/website.git"`

It should be

`"homepage": "https://shivam242001.github.io"`

Please refer to this: https://github.com/gitname/react-gh-pages#4-add-a-homepage-property-to-the-packagejson-file